# What is this thing?

Tags: support

While reading the answers to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/97975/why-is-the-word-r%C3%B6tschreck-spelled-with-an-umlaut), I noticed this *thing*:

[image]

> Some of the information contained in this post requires additional references. Please edit to add citations to reliable sources that support the assertions made here. Unsourced material may be disputed or deleted.

I would like to propose one of these *things* on another stack I am active on. However, I'm not sure what the terminology is (what do I call it?) or how it works (does it appear through votes by the community or does a mod apply it?).

The CSS refers to it as a "post notice" - something which I have never before heard of on this site.

So ... what is it?